# mac os 12.0.1: create a bootable Windows 7 USB for old laptop

Tags: windows, osx, usb, bootable

I need to install windows 7 on an old laptop and my only working PC is a mac (OS 12.0.1) right now, so I need to create a bootable USB from the mac for the PC with the .iso file of a windows7. I believe Boot Camp is not doing the job anymore (maybe somebody can explain what happened).

I found just a software for the newest mac OS which would do the job (not 100% sure), called uubyte. balenaEtcher did not work properly.

Is there something like rufus for macs or what would you propose?

PD: I also tried the command line way mounting the .iso and did not work.

Comment: BTW, get rid of 12.0.1 as soon as you possibly can, then try balena again. the initial release of Monterey was one of Apple's buggiest ever first releases. 12.1 was better, 12.2 apparently better sill. [General rule, never upgrade until the point two version at least. You can live without the new bells & whistles for a couple of months.]

Comment: Also - mounting the Win ISO is not the way to make bootable media. The ISO content itself is not bootable; it only becomes a bootable installer once it's been through Windows Media Creator [or balena at a push].

Answer (score 0):

macOS cannot make Windows installer media. BalenaEtcher is about the only 3rd party software that 'kind of works'. You really need Windows to make Windows [just like you need a Mac to make macOS bootables].

Boot Camp is your best bet, so long as you're not on an M1 Mac. [I have no idea if Windows for ARM can make Windows for Intel bootables.]